# NoMethodError: undefined method `configure' for main:Object on sinatra project

Tags: postgresql, sinatra

So I was following this good-if-rather-old tutorial on setting up a postgres db with Sinatra: http://mherman.org/blog/2013/06/08/designing-with-class-sinatra-plus-postgresql-plus-heroku/

I've setup my environments.rb as suggested, and the rake file, as shown below:

```
configure :development do
  set :database, "sqlite:///dev.db"
  set :show_exceptions, true
end

configure :production do
  db = URI.parse(ENV["DATABASE_URL"] || 'postgres:///localhost/mydb')

  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
    :host => db.host,
    :username => db.user,
    :password => db.password,
    :database => db.path[1..-1],
    :encoding => 'utf8'
  )

end
```

and:

```
require './app_name'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
```

When I try to create the migration using:

```
rake db:create_migration NAME=create_applicants
```

It errors with this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `configure' for main:Object
/Users/harxy/Projects/bridgey/environments.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Any thoughts on what might be going wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the Sinatra gem installed? Are you calling ```require 'sinatra'``` anywhere? See for example this template: https://github.com/zapnap/sinatra-template/blob/master/environment.rb

Comment: Yeah so this was basically it. Even in their example on github they don't have require 'sinatra' in their environments.rb file... very odd. But it's working, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment above by Jack Bracken, you need `require 'sinatra'` in your environments.rb file for this to work.